# SqlAlchemy + Celery with Scoped Session error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I am trying to run a celery_beat job that kicks off a bunch of parallel jobs, but am getting the error: `ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

Here are my relevant files.  Notice that I am using a scoped_session:

```py
#db.py
engine = create_engine(SETTINGS['DATABASE_URL'], pool_recycle=3600, pool_size=10)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
```

```py
#tasks.py
from db import db_session
@app.task
def db_task(pid):

    db_session()
    r = db_session.query(exists().where(RSSSummary.id == pid)).scalar()

    print pid, r
    db_session.remove()


@app.task
def sched_test():
    ids =[0, 1]

    db_task.delay(ids[0])
    db_task.delay(ids[1])
```

And then when I try initiate `sched_test`, like so:

```py
>>> tasks.sched_test.delay()
```

`DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq`

and

`ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`

I believe I am using scoped_sessions properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of concurrency are you using for celery?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean. I should be running 4 threads. Here is what I believe to be the relevant output:

    `concurrency: 4 (prefork)`

Comment: I think that means you're running four processes in prefork mode. In prefork mode you need to be careful that you don't start any DB connections before forking, lest you share those connections among all your processes. It looks like celery doesn't support post-fork, so your options are either to eliminate those connections before forking or use gevent.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error along with some errors like:

```
DatabaseError: server sent data ("D" message) without prior row description ("T" message)
lost synchronization with server: got message type "�", length -1244613424

DatabaseError: lost synchronization with server: got message type "0", length 842674226
```

It turns out that this was because my Celery worker processes were sharing the SQLAlchemy connections.  [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing) address this:

> It’s critical that when using a connection pool, and by extension when
>   using an Engine created via create_engine(), that the pooled
>   connections are not shared to a forked process. TCP connections are
>   represented as file descriptors, which usually work across process
>   boundaries, meaning this will cause concurrent access to the file
>   descriptor on behalf of two or more entirely independent Python
>   interpreter states.

I fixed this by using Celery events to invalidate all existing connections in the pool upon startup of the worker:

```py
from celery.signals import worker_process_init

@worker_process_init.connect
def prep_db_pool(**kwargs):
    """
        When Celery fork's the parent process, the db engine & connection pool is included in that.
        But, the db connections should not be shared across processes, so we tell the engine
        to dispose of all existing connections, which will cause new ones to be opend in the child
        processes as needed.
        More info: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing
    """
    # The "with" here is for a flask app using Flask-SQLAlchemy.  If you don't 
    # have a flask app, just remove the "with" here and call .dispose()
    # on your SQLAlchemy db engine.
    with some_flask_app.app_context():
        db.engine.dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Just spent the past 4-6 hours trying to solve this. I have various apps with celery/sqlalchemy/postgres with the same setup, but one particular blew up with these errors. This one is connected to an external database (not on my local machine). Everything is orchestrated with docker-compose. Any idea why the external DB blows up and the internal ones don't? This one also has a tad bit more complex queries (though execution time is probably < 200 ms)...

Comment: > Any idea why the external DB blows up and the internal ones don't? 

@borisdonchev it's possible its because your external connections stay active longer due to latency of going across the network.  Or, it's possible your external connections are more active than your local ones.  Remember this is a "shared resource" issue.  So the longer or more frequently that resource is in use the more likely it is for it to get shared.  My guess is your external db connections are in use longer and/or more frequently.