# psycopg2.DatabaseError: error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq error in Flask Celery app

Tags: python, flask, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

At random occurrences, I notice such errors in the Flask Celery application that uses SQLAlchemy.

When I check database connectivity, it is fine. It seems the app somehow loses connection to the PostgreSQL database server.

```
    [2021-02-08 00:01:00,124: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task gbms.celery_service.create_recurring_tasks[04c258ab-9162-44ed-86ff-f90c4a214fd2] raised unexpected: DatabaseError('(psycopg2.DatabaseError) error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gbmsenv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/gbmsenv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.DatabaseError: error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

What steps should I take to identify the cause and fix the issue?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751019/5320906).